# Wording for constant in time

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Hi I'm writing a scientific paper and want to write something along the line of:

"Static in time" objects are ...

Is there a single word describing time independent?

Comment: Please supply more background information. Are these objects abstract entities, physical objects, geographical locations...?

Comment: Time-independent _is_ a single word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something constant over time might be [*immutable*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3aimmutable) or [*unchanging*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3aunchanging), in that it is the same now as it was before and as it will be in the future.

It may also be [*permanent*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3apermanent) if its existence is unchanging, or even [*eternal*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3aeternal) or [*timeless*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3atimeless) if time has no effect on it and/or it does not age.

Comment: Immutable was exaclty the word I was looking for thank you.

Comment: Then what you mean is static in **space** through time; i.e, f(`t1`) = f(`t2`) for all `tn`. "Static in time" makes no sense.